# Weird character zsh in emacs terminal

Tags: macos, emacs, zsh

When using the terminal in emacs (M-x term) under MacOS for some reason it always posts the characters 4m before every line in zsh and always prints 2 lines containing the user info such as

```
4m--(jesus@laptop:/dir)----
4m--(jesus@laptop:/dir)----
prompt>
```

It's more of an annoyance than anything but I was just wondering if there's a way to fix this. I also seem to have issues in Zsh in Mac OS emacs terminal mode when a lot of output is written to it it seems to reduce it all to one line and constantly overwrite the same line (may be related as the 4m is possibly just a special character that emacs is treating differently which can affect formatting).

If need be I can post my .zshrc and .emacs files.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You don't have eterm-color terminfo.
First, you try to add following S-exp in your configuration file and evaluate.

```
;; Use Emacs terminfo, not system terminfo
(setq system-uses-terminfo nil)
```

If problem is not resolved previous setting, you should create eterm-color terminfo
by using following command. (terminfo path may different from your system)

```
# If you use Cocoa Emacs or Carbon Emacs
tic -o ~/.terminfo /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/e/eterm-color.ti
```

Comment: Turns out Cocoa Emacs when installed from emacsformacosx.com does not install this file. So if you're using emacs from there, you'll need to run the second command above.

Comment: I had to get a copy of the eterm-color.ti from http://opensource.apple.com/source/emacs/emacs-70/emacs/etc/e/eterm-color.ti?txt

Comment: Anybody got an update on this? The structure of the Emacs Cocoa app, changed... and eterm-color.ti isn't located at /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/e/eterm-color.ti anymore :(

Comment: Look for the file in /usr/share/emacs/22.1/etc/e/eterm-color.ti

Comment: Where can the .terminfo file be found? If you are using a Mac as well, then where did you get it from?

Comment: I'm using an emacs installed via Homebrew on OSX. Added the S-exp... no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Recent Emacs which is installed by homebrew works well without this setting. Please upgrade emacs and try again.

Comment: I still had to do terminfo setting with the latest Homebrew Emacs. I've used `tic -o ~/.terminfo /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.3/share/emacs/24.3/etc/e/eterm-color.ti`

Comment: Wow, the second part of the answer worked fine for me! Thanks.

Comment: There's some more information about this in `Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/e/README` as well. I was able to fix the '4m' problem by running `tic -o ../ ./eterm-color.ti` from that directory.

Answer (score 9):

I needed to set the following environment variables in my ~/.zshrc

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Answer (score 1):

This installed `eterm-color.ti` for me on OSX Mavericks 10.9.5:

1. Upload [`eterm-color.ti`](https://gist.github.com/scottjacobsen/27565062eeecd6a19c70) to `/tmp` on the remote OSX server.
2. Run the command `sudo tic -o /usr/share/terminfo /tmp/eterm-color.ti` on the server.

In my case, this put a file `eterm-color` in the directory `/usr/share/terminfo/65/`