# Emacs multi-term not displaying special characters correctly

Tags: emacs, terminal, zsh, ansi-term

This is odd. I have defined the following prompt in `zsh`:

```
local user_host='%{$terminfo[bold]$fg[green]%}%n @ %m%{$reset_color%}'
local current_dir='%{$terminfo[bold]$fg[blue]%} %~%{$reset_color%}'
local git_branch='$(git_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%}'
local return_code="%(?..%{$fg[red]%}%? ↵%{$reset_color%})"

PROMPT="╭─${user_host} %D{[%a, %b %d %I:%M:%S]} ${current_dir} ${git_branch}
╰─%B$%b "
RPS1="${return_code}"
```

It works great on `gnome-terminal` as well as in an `ansi-term` terminal in Emacs (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `ansi-term`) - see the example below:

[image: prompt example gnome-terminal/ansi-term]

However, it does not work well under `multi-term` in Emacs as you can see below:

[image: prompt example multi-term]

I thought `multi-term` would be capable of interpreting the same set of escape characters that a terminal like  `gnome-terminal` or `ansi-term` does. Why is it not interpreting the escape characters returned by `git-prompt_info` and others correctly?

I have also tried:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-terminal-coding-system` and setting it to `utf-8-unix`
- `TERM=eterm-color` within the multi-term terminal, or before calling Emacs, etc.
- `TERM=` within the multi-term terminal, or before calling Emacs, etc.
- Removing any `export TERM` from my `.zshrc`

## Update (January 29, 2014):

The best solution so far seems to be to do the following:

`TERM=xterm-256color`

but causes another problem that I have reported here: [Passing escape sequences to shells within ansi-term in Emacs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111541/passing-escape-sequences-to-zsh-embedded-shells-within-ansi-term-in-emacs).

Comment: Check the answer here to see if that works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918910/weird-character-zsh-in-emacs-terminal

Comment: Thanks @JesusRamos That worked great for `ansi-term`! For some reason it is not enough for Emacs `multi-term` (which is supposed to extend ansi-term) ... Hmmm

Comment: I stopped using multi term and instead I just do `M-x rename-buffer` myself. It works just fine that way :)

Comment: Two things you might want to check. 1. `TERM` should be `eterm-color` in the emacs terminal buffer. 2. The coding system should be set to `utf-8-unix`. `M-x set-terminal-coding-system`. Default value can be set in the variable `default-terminal-coding-system`

Comment: Thanks @mikyra. I currently have `export TERM='xterm-256color'` in my `.zshrc`. Should I change that to `eterm-color` then?.

Comment: No, no. `TERM=xterm-256color` is pretty fine. I also use it with `gnome-terminal`. Just **don't** `export` it. A single `TERM=xterm-256color` is enough. If "exported" emacs seems to somehow get confused and doesn't set it to `eterm-color` in term-mode leaving it defined as `xterm-256color` giving some funny effects especially with programs making heavy use of ncurses and the like.

Comment: Thanks @mikyra I removed `export`, but interestingly if I open a `multi-term` in Emacs, and I do `echo $TERM` I still get `xterm-256color`.. Hmmm

Comment: I seem to have the same problem, however the link you suggest didn't help me. As the structure of the Cocoa app changed. Got any clues what to do? If I ``export TERM='xterm-256color'``to in my .zshrc, then the 4m goes away... while the unicode characters still manage to not get properly displayed.

Comment: Did you finally solve this? Can you post a response?

Comment: @YuppieNetworking I haven't solved this yet. The best solution I came up with was using `TERM='xterm-256color'` as the comments above report, **BUT** this gives me other problems, see [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111541/passing-escape-sequences-to-zsh-embedded-shells-within-ansi-term-in-emacs)

Comment: `TERM=xterm-256color` fixed my issue. I wouldn't be surprised if it made something else break, but I'm not going to search that out -- I've been down that road and it ends in tears.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it not interpreting the escape characters returned by
>   git-prompt_info and others correctly?

The answer is most likely that `multi-term` just isn't prepared to accept those escape sequences, in that format, for whatever reason.  This may be a configuration issue, bug, or intentional.  Setting the mode to accept colors, i.e. `TERM=xterm-256color`, improves the situation because it then accepts color escape sequences similar to the standard format used among terminal emulators, e.g.:

```
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
echo "I ${RED}love${NC} Stack Overflow\n" # this output IS NOT interpreting the escapes
echo -e "I ${RED}love${NC} Stack Overflow\n" # this output IS interpreting them
```

<sup>[code borrowed from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux/5947802#5947802)</sup>

the salient part is the `[0;31m` for color, which is referenced in the linked thread in "Update 2" of your other question, asking why lines are printed out that begin with `4m` which is part of this color escape sequence.

Here is more [info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158412/are-the-terminal-color-escape-sequences-defined-anywhere-for-bash/158421#158421), with a relevant excerpt:

> Thus it is your terminal emulator that understands colors. Your
>   terminal emulator understands that `\033[0;36m` is cyan, but another
>   terminal emulator might use an entirely different set of characters
>   for cyan (though no sane terminal emulator would flaunt the standard
>   and do this). This is the reason for `tput`. When you run `tput setaf
>   6`, `tput` is going to look up your terminal's escape codes for the
>   color 6 (cyan), and output that escape code.

I suspect, in your other question, the reason that <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> aren't working in your other question is due to the terminal width count being off because of improper interpretation of these escape sequences which are supposed to be non-printing or zero-width.  I haven't messed with `multi-term` a lot but the solution may involve using `tput` or similar to allow it to properly understand the escape sequences.

[Possible relevant troubleshooting info](http://rawsyntax.com/blog/learn-emacs-zsh-and-multi-term/)

Comment: That's a lot of words, but not particularly helpful (a good answer might point to the [documentation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm) and note that the relevant part is `term.el` (no "xterm" anything).