# Emacs shell with ZSH, I get weird characters

Tags: emacs, debian, zsh

I want to use emacs with zsh in debian 8, my locales are es_ES,

```
 uname -a
Linux toshiba-debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

normally it goes well but sometypes I get Weir characters like ^G or someting like this:

```
╭─anquegi@toshiba-debian  ~/Descargas ‹ruby-2.2.1@laguna› 
╰─$ lm
zsh: correct 'lm' to 'ln' [nyae]? ^Gn
n
```

or

```
╭─anquegi@toshiba-debian  ~/Descargas ‹ruby-2.2.1@laguna› 
╰─$ pry
^[[0G[1] pry(main)>
```

I tried  a lot of things like the two first answer here, but nothing works

[Weird character zsh in emacs terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918910/weird-character-zsh-in-emacs-terminal)

I do not know what to do next

Comment: Try [AnsiTerm](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm). But overall, yes, Emacs terminal is not capable of all things

Comment: This answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918910/weird-character-zsh-in-emacs-terminal